# Why fetch() does not exit in for loop?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, fetch

I use fetch() to print labels. There are some scenario when I need to loop through the data and print multiple labels. The printing it's working fine, but after the first loop the script stop running.

I use async function in order to slow down a printing.

```
async function printing() {

    for (let w = 0; w < print_labels.length; w++) {
       
        const label = `data of the label`

        fetch('http://111.111.1.111:9100', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: label
        })
        
        console.log(`${w}. label printed.`)
        await sleep(2000);


    }
}; 
printing()
```

Ho can I cancel/stop the fetch() function? Or maybe any other solution how to use fetch() post in for loop?

Answer (score 0):

`AbortController` needs to be used to abort requests, as another answer mentions. Both failed and aborted `fetch` will throw errors, and errors need to be correctly handled in order to not cause exceptions.

Generally request promise needs to be awaited. In this case `race` can be used to handle both request and delay promises:

```
let controller = new AbortController();

try {
  await Promise.race([
    fetch(..., { ... , signal: controller.signal }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve);
      controller.abort();
    }, 2000);
  ]));
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Failed');
}
```

Aborted request causes an error that can be detected with `err.name === 'AbortError'` check and suppressed if necessary, but in this case this may not be needed because delay promise resolves first on timeout and makes `Promise.race` resolve with `undefined` with `AbortError` being suppressed.

Comment: I've got a similar error id, but now without printing: 
"(node:13948) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Failed
Failed"

Comment: See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30810#issuecomment-1336207831 . This is not related to the question as you'd have the warning regardless of what you do. Notice that the request isn't completed within 2s may designate that there's something wrong on server side and it's not good to cancel a request after 2s if it's expected to take several.